# Permanently increase 'Recent Documents'

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

I've tried to look around for a similar question but it didn't seem as though there was one, so here's my case:

I've tried to increase the number of recent documents in MS Word/Excel for a while now from 9 (I think that's the default) to 13 but without success. It works only as long as the file is open and resets to 9 when I close and open a new file.

I would have expected it to save the 'preferences' if I can call it like that, but that doesn't happen for some reason. Has anyone ever got something like that and found a solution?

I'm on Word and Excel 2007, Windows XP SP3 (if this is relevant).

Let me know if there's any more information that might help and I'll add it.

**EDIT:** Oops, it actually works on Word. It was probably on my previous laptop that it wasn't working. It doesn't work in Excel though. I removed the MS Word tag.

[image]
[image]

**reEDIT**:

It seems that the problem is related to the add-in that we usually use at work. I have upgraded from Excel-2007 to Excel-2010 but the problem persists.

I also just noticed that I have not installed this add-in on my laptop upon upgrade, while I did on my desktop and the problem is occurring only on my desktop.

Now, I'm a bit curious about what's in that add-in, to see how exactly this setting is being enforced so as to be able to change it or disable it.

Sorry that the problem had something specific to the software and environment instead of something generic :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to know how to change 9 to 13 so appear to be missing only how to make this your default. Gord Dibben gives advice on that [here](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/template-default-excel-2007-a-t3889268.html):

Open a new workbook.
Make your changes to this workbook.
Save As>File Type>Template (*.xltx)
Save into your XLSTART folder.
You now have a default New Workbook.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately it's not working for me. I even tried saving as an add-in instead (I'm not sure how they work, so... =S) Could it have to be do to another template or add-in? It's my work laptop and there might be some preset stuff, though there's nothing in the XLSTART folder. What makes it strangest is that it works for Word...

Comment: I added screenshots of excel which hopefully answers.

Comment: I'm not on a network all the time either. I am right now, but when I'm not more on the network, I still cannot make the recent documents permanent. Or does that still matter?

Comment: Yes, each time I change it to 13 (it remains 13 as long as I don't close excel completely), and close excel and reopen it, it has reset to 9.

Comment: Correct. Do you think there might be another path were I could have an XLSTART folder?

Comment: That's okay, thanks for having the patience with this problem of mine, I appreciate it :)